# Which is correct ,more wary or warier?

Tags: adjectives

It is more wary or warier ?
If more wary is correct (I reckon it is because I read it in a test) is it common ?

Answer (score 2):

Both "more wary" and "warier" are possible and correct.

The basic adjective "wary" is pretty rare word anyway and the comparative forms are very rare. Some searching finds "warier" being used poetically, for the rhyme in

> Be warier in Bulgaria! (about investment in Bulgarian companies)

and prosaically in

> Why Britons are warier than other Europeans of the EU.

There are more citations for "more wary"

> Investors Are More Wary of Trump Than of Wall Street.
>   Manufacturers were more wary about what lies ahead.

Note that most of the use of "wary" in modern English seems to be in a financial, or political/economic context. Often a synonym can be found, such as "distrustful" or "concerned about".

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's *wary-warier-wariest* Looked it up in Oxford Dictionaries and found this: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/wary 
The definition from the Collins English Dictionary: 
https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/wary